# Why is AllowNull() not doing anything?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have the following command call

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -switch1 "$DBN" "$($Server[-1])" "$Creds" "$ConnectionID" "$ConnectionDataSource"
```

I want to make ConnectionID and Connection DataSource optional

How can I do that?

This command is only working if I input something for ConnectionID and Connection Data Source. otherwise, they won't work if I don't input anything for these two params!

here are the params in this script1.ps1 (which I am calling IN script2.ps1):

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DBN,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Server,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$Creds,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a UserID for the connection")]
    [string]$ConnectionID, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a Data Source for the connection. Must enter the ConnectionID first")]
    [string]$ConnectionDataSource
)
```

Here are the params in this `script2.ps1` (which I am calling `script1.ps1` from):

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DBN,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a UserID for the connection")]
    [string]$ConnectionID, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a Data Source for the connection. Must enter the ConnectionID first")]
    [string]$ConnectionDataSource
)
```

Running `script1.ps1` without these 2 inputs works just fine.

I run it like this:

```
PS> script1.ps1 DB1 Server1
```

so I know I have to do something here in the call operator of this second script I'm calling script1 from

I'm looking for something like this:

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -switch1 "$DBN" "$($Server[-1])" "$Creds" [optional]"$ConnectionID" [optional]"$ConnectionDataSource"
```

I tried the `[AllowNull()]` attribute in script1 and 2

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a UserID for the connection")]
[AllowNull()]
[string]$ConnectionID, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a Data Source for the connection. Must enter the ConnectionID first")]
[AllowNull()]
[string]$ConnectionDataSource
```

but it still results in error from script2:

> script1.ps1: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ConnectionDataSource' because it is an empty string.

Comment: Works fine for me. Please create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, then [edit] your question and show the exact code of both scripts, how you invoke them, and the full error message.